# LogicalKeyboardKey.meta in shortcut is triggered without pressing the other keys in the LogicalKeySet

Tags: flutter, keyboard-shortcuts, flutter-web

I've been working with `Shortcuts`, `Actions` and key binds with Flutter web. And I've found a weird behaviour that I can't find a solution to.

The thing is, I have defined a series of `LogicalKeySet` for a set of actions. I create 2 per action, one for windows and one for mac. They look something like this:

```dart
final boldKeySetWindows = LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.control, LogicalKeyboardKey.keyB);
final boldKeySetMac = LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.control, LogicalKeyboardKey.keyB);
```

I add them to the Actions widget as specified [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/actions_and_shortcuts).

```dart
final boldKeySetWindows = LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.control, LogicalKeyboardKey.keyB);
final boldKeySetMac = LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.control, LogicalKeyboardKey.keyB);

Shortcuts(
  shortcuts: {
    boldKeySetWindows: MEFormatIntent(boldFormatter),
    boldKeySetMac: MEFormatIntent(boldFormatter),
  },
  child: Actions(
    dispatcher: MEFormatActionDispatcher(),
    actions: <Type, Action<Intent>>{
      MEFormatIntent: MEFormatAction(_controller),
    },
  )
);
```

The problem or weird behaviour is the following, for windows (using control) it works fine, it only executes `MEFormatAction` when both `ctrl` and `b` are pressed.

But if I try using the `meta` key or `⌘` key plus `b` it works correctly the first time you press `cmd+b`, but after that, if I quickly press `cmd` again, it executes `MEFormatAction` again. (This behaviour does not happen with `ctrl`)

Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

I have not tried anything as I have been unsuccessful in finding information regarding this behaviour, any help or advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue/behaviour, it seems an issue with MacOS, more information can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103964) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97589#issuecomment-1058750417)

But the solution is to use, SingleActivator instead of LogicalKeySet